# Softmax groups in a tensor by a group index from a second tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking for a way to softmax parts of a tensor x by their group, which is denoted by a group index y[i], that exists for each element of x. Here's some code:

```
x = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3])
y = tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

z = <some_operation>(x, y)       # -> softmax [0.1, 0.2] and softmax [0.05, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3]
                                 # -> outputs a tensor of shape [6]
```

Reshaping is not an option I think as the groups to be softmaxed have different sizes.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: How big is the number of groups compared to the dimensionality of `x`?

Comment: definitely less. Maybe by an order of magnitude

Comment: Would something which is O(N G) work for you where N is len(x) and G is the number of groups? Or are you looking for an O(N) solution?

Comment: The faster the better ;) I have figured out a possible solution. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? The "manual way" to calculate it

```
x = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3])
y = tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

es = tf.math.exp(x)
es_sums = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(data=es,
                                  segment_ids=y,
                                  num_segments=tf.math.reduce_max(y)+1)

es_sums = tf.gather(es_sums, y)
softmaxes = es / es_sums

with tf.Session() as s:
    print(s.run(softmaxes))         # [0.4750208  0.5249792  0.21648198 0.27796838 0.22758126 0.27796838]
```